# WinSCP network connection time out. Windows 10

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

I am unable to connect to SFTP server using WinSCP. 
It works fine from another server on Windows Server 2012r.

But does not work on local.

What else should I try?

[image]

What I've done:

Added WinScp.exe as an exception in firewall:

[image]

Make sure Open Open SSH Client is installed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by modifying the host file on windows 10.
Follow this example: https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-modify-your-hosts-file-in-windows-10-and-why-you-might-want-to

Comment: This is hardly a generic solution to the problem. Would you please explain, why it was necessary in this specific case?